# Java: Confining Robot simlated keypresses to the application itself

Tags: java, jframe, awt, keyevent

Good day everyone,

I would like to find out how I could confine all robot simulated keypresses and mouse movements to the application itself. I am currently working on a small project, creating a music player for google music.

I could make the window focusable before executing the robot code, but that causes too much hastles for the music player being in system tray and also it would unfocus game windows set to full screen.

```
private void Play(){
        try {                           
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(32);
            robot.keyRelease(32);   
        } catch (AWTException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

That is currently the robot code to play/pause. It is currently simulating the space key being pressed.

Partial Solution

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(Component, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 0, 0, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, char Action)); // Component you want the key press to go
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch key events directly to the text component.  The frame doesn't need to have focus for this to work.

```
text.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(text,
                                KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 
                                0,
                                0,
                                KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, 
                                'H'));
```

If you want to do this from the EDT, set it up with invokeLater:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        text.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(text,
                                KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 
                                0,
                                0,
                                KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, 
                                'H'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain this more? I'm trying out the code, can't seem to figure how it works

Comment: You need to expose the text component you want to receive the key events - this is `text` in the above example.

Comment: Sorry if there is confusion, but I don't want to get input from the user. I'm trying to output spacebar keypress within the java window itself without focusing on the window.

Comment: That's what this code does - it acts like the Robot class, but instead of targeting the currently focused window it targets a specific component.  The KeyEvent you dispatch is created by your code, not by user input.

Comment: Oh eh, guess that makes sense then. Could you please assist me on setting up, this is my first time using this method. 

this.dispatchEvent(this, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 0, 0, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, 'H'); // Extended my class as a JFrame

So first KeyEvent becomes KeyEvent.VK_SPACE to simulate the space being pressed

first 0, stays the same so does the second

Then the second keyevent stays the same??

Apparently having a char at the end breaks the dispatch method. pastebin for formatted spaces: http://pastebin.com/jqLbePJ5

Comment: Update your question with the details.  Also, you don't need to `press` and `release` if you use `KEY_TYPED`. Just replace `'H'` with `' '`.

Comment: Okay ty for the tips. I almost have it. ' ' simulates the spacing and not the space bar being pressed. I'm going to try and find a way to get it to work later.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with creating spacebar being the keypressed. Atm, when I execute the method it scrolls down much like if you click a empty space in the browser and pressed space bar. char ' ' isn't working.